# want to extract data from a site using selenium-wedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I want to extract the name, website, phone, and email of every company on the site but the code keeps printing the first company name on the page over and over and crashs if I try to find the website, phone, and email.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

url='https://www.dmcc.ae/business-search?directory=1&submissionGuid=2c8df029-a92e-4b5d-a014-7ef9948e664b'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,50)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hs-eu-confirmation-button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#pym-0 > iframe')))
list=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'searched-list ')))
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'./html/body/div[5]/div/ul/li[13]/a')))



numOfPages=1161
counter=4

for i in range(numOfPages):

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)

    for e in list:
        name = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4').text
        print(name)
        website = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a').text
        print(website)
        phone = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a').text
        print(phone)
        email = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a').text
        print(email)
 
    time.sleep(counter)  
    button.click()
    list=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'searched-list ')))
    if i%40==0:
        counter+=1
```

my problem is with these lines of code

```
list=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'searched-list ')))
```

```
 for e in list:
        name = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4').text
        print(name)
        website = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a').text
        print(website)
        phone = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a').text
        print(phone)
        email = e.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a').text
        print(email)
```

Comment: Data that you are searching is in iframe. You need to switch to iframe and than use the find by

Comment: I have switched to the iframe                                                                                        here
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#pym-0 > iframe')))

Comment: Did nor see iframe impementation. ...I see the space (By.CLASS_NAME,'searched-list ') on the end. Try use  By.CSSSELECTOR('searched-list.ng-scope').
And let me know was that heplfull

Comment: I tried it it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would you suggest to use other functions of finding elements to make your code more readable. I've made a couple of changes in your code, hope that helps you to get the data:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


url = "https://www.dmcc.ae/business-search?directory=1&submissionGuid=2c8df029-a92e-4b5d-a014-7ef9948e664b"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)

wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hs-eu-confirmation-button"))
).click()
wait.until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pym-0 > iframe"))
)
list = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "list-title ")))
button = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[ng-click='setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)']")
    )
)

counter = 4


def getText(element):
    text = element.text

    if not text:
        text = "---"

    return text


def getContactInfo(parent):
    element = None
    try:
        element = parent.find_element_by_class_name("contact-info")
    except:
        pass

    return element

while (
    # Last Page has disabled the li element
    not "disabled"
    in driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "li[ng-class='{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}']"
    )
    .get_attribute("class")
    .split()
):

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)

    for e in list:
        name = e.find_element_by_tag_name("h4")
        print(getText(name))
        account_info = e.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "div.account-Info.large-12.columns.ng-scope"
        )
        contact_info = getContactInfo(account_info)

        if contact_info:
            website = contact_info.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "a.website.ng-binding.ng-scope"
            )
            print(getText(website))
            phone = contact_info.find_element_by_css_selector("a.telephone.ng-binding")
            print(getText(phone))
            email = contact_info.find_element_by_css_selector("a.emailid.ng-binding")
            print(getText(email))

        print("*******\n")

    button.click()
    time.sleep(counter)
    list = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "list-title "))
    )

driver.quit()
```

Comment: thank you for helping and the edits, I wanted to know if there is a way to put a (-) sign or just a blank on companies that don't have a phone or email or website.

Comment: sure, check the edits, i've added a function that handles those situations

Comment: sorry for bothering you, if you run the code you see that some of the companies have no phone on the site but when you run the code some phone numbers get duplicated from over companies that have a phone to other that doesn't, have a phone number